# Video duration is sometimes NaN

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, html-input

I have a video and a slider beneath it.

- Video is played by click on it.
- When video is playing slider should move accordingly.
- By manually moving the slider, video should be updated.

```js
// Video duration is available when page is ready/loaded?
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    slider.min = 0
    slider.value = 0
    slider.max = vid.duration * 1000

    // TODO: for some reason, slider max is NaN sometimes!
    console.log('slider min', slider.min)
    console.log('slider max', slider.max)
  }
}

// Play/pause by click on video.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
vid.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play()
  } else {
    vid.pause()
  }
});

// When video is playing, move slider accordingly.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  t = this.currentTime
  slider.value = t * 1000
});

// Update the video when you drag the slider handle.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
slider.oninput = function() {
  vid.currentTime = slider.value / 1000.0
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* The slider itself */

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  /* Full-width? */
  height: 5px;
  /* Specified height */
  background: #d3d3d3;
  /* Grey background */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity .2s;
}


/* Mouse-over effects */

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}


/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #AA0000;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 5px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #AA0000;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <video id="vid" style="width: 50%;">
      <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source id='webm' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source id='ogv' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg' />Your browser does not support the vedio tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer" style="width: 100%;">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

## Question

For some reason, sometimes the slider `max` is set to video duration correctly:

[image: Correct]

However, sometimes the slider `max` value is `NaN`:

[image: Wrong: NaN]

Specifically, when opening the `index.html` locally on my laptop the slider `max` is good. But when deploying to server, the slider `max` is `NaN`. I cannot figure out why that's observed!

## Solved

Fixed code is this, the trick is `preload="metadata"` and `onloadedmetadata`:

```js
// 100.0 means slider resolution is 1/100 of a second.
window.sliderResolution = 100.0

// Slider max is set when the metadata is loaded.
// To avoid slider max being NaN sometimes.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid")
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange")
vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  slider.min = 0
  slider.value = 0
  slider.max = vid.duration * window.sliderResolution

  console.log('slider min', slider.min)
  console.log('slider max', slider.max)

  // Show slider when video metadata is loaded.
  var slideParent = document.getElementById("slideparent")
  slideParent.style.visibility = "visible"
};

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    console.log('Doc is ready')
  }
}

// Play/pause by click on video.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
vid.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play()
  } else {
    vid.pause()
  }
});

// When video is playing, move slider accordingly.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  t = this.currentTime
  slider.value = t * window.sliderResolution
});

// Update the video when you drag the slider handle.
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
slider.oninput = function() {
  vid.currentTime = slider.value / window.sliderResolution
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* The slider itself */

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  /* Full-width? */
  height: 5px;
  /* Specified height */
  background: #d3d3d3;
  /* Grey background */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity .2s;
}


/* Mouse-over effects */

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}


/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #AA0000;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 5px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #AA0000;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <video id="vid" preload="metadata" style="width: 50%;">
      <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source id='webm' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source id='ogv' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg' />Your browser does not support the vedio tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;" id="slideparent">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're not waiting for the video's metadata to be loaded, so `duration` is still `NaN`.

Comment: In your **readystate** check, maybe start with the slider hidden (`slider.style.visibility = "hidden";`). You also need `vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => { slider.max = vid.duration * 1000;  showSlider(); } )` where the `showSlider` function later on will do `slider.style.visibility = "visible";` thus making it usable only when metadata has given you the duration...

Comment: PS: by `slider` in above I mean the container `slidecontainer`. So maybe give that div an **id** to reference it with when setting the visiblity.

Comment: @VC.One Right  =) It's a good idea to hide slider until video metadata is loaded